# Use gulp with angular2 - ES5 or ES6

Tags: gulp, angular

I've added angular 2 to my project and it works, but I want to add gulp.

When I used target: ES5 in my package.json file then I received many errors and after reading this ( https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7052 ) I added

```
  ///<reference path="node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
```

to my boot.ts file and it works. When I changed ES5 to ES6 I don't need this line. Could somebody explain which one should I use ?

Answer (score 0):

If the question is

> Should I use ES5 or ES6

The answer is, it depends on your project and its requirements. Some aspects of ES6 is supported in all major, up-to-date, browsers today except for Safari for desktop. However, it does leave people with older browsers out and not all aspects of ES6 is supported yet. But you are not likely to use the new features of ES6 if you don't know about them.

So, decide which browsers you need to support, look at https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/
and make a decision yourself

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved in latest beta, 2.0.0-beta.7. Just update your angular2 installation and you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: I have 2.0.0-beta.7 and it's still present there